# Mostrar en vista, dato (Fecha) que viene desde el controlador ASP.Net MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, date, datetime, razor

Buen día, estoy tratando de mostrar un dato de tipo fecha en mi vista, esto en la sección Editar al mandar la la información a editar se manda con éxito todo incluyendo la fecha perteneciente al mismo, la fecha se muestra en un

`@Html.EditorFor( model => model.FechaFin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

mostrándose como un input normal (caja de texto), al querer cambiarlo con
`@type = "datetime-local"` o  `<input class="form-control chosen-select" type="datetime" name="Fecha" id="Fecha" value="model => model.FechaFin">`
me cambia el tipo de input pero no me muestra el valor fecha que recibe

vista:

```
  <div  class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaFin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor( model => model.FechaFin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "datetime-local", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaFin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
               @* <input class="form-control chosen-select" type="datetime" name="Fecha" id="Fecha" value="model => model.FechaFin">*@

            </div>
        </div>
```

controlador:

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
 Eq_tblMantenimientos eq_TblMantenimientos = db.Eq_tblMantenimientos.Find(id);



                    return View(eq_TblMantenimientos);

}
```

cabe destacar que los datos que recibe son de tipo datetime

Comment: Se me ocurre que puede ser que la fecha te esta llegando en otro orden al que te pide el formato intenta hacer un cast con la fecha para que te los ordene como te pide el formato de fecha tu input

Comment: Acabode intentarlo y funciona pero al momento de cambiar a  type ="Date" para que me despliegue el pequeño calendario, sigue mostrandome el campo vacio